# Comment traduire les termes reliés aux gestionnaires de version ?

Tags: informatique, terminologie

Je pense aux opérations de base dans les programmes comme SVN :

- Checkout
- Commit

Les autres termes me semblent plutôt clairs :

- Trunk : Tronc
- Branch : Branche
- Conflict : Conflit
- Lock : Verrouiller
- etc.

J'ai essayé des équivalents, mais rien n'y semble faire. Est-ce que des organismes ont statué sur des traductions officielles ?

Comment: Le langage utilisé devient souvent comique en français. "J'ai commité ça" ou encore "J'ai commis ça". Le second semble naturel, mais a une connotation criminelle...

Comment: Si c'est une traduction qui va être lue principalement par des programmeurs, alors il vaut mieux utiliser "commiter" ou "faire un commit" qui sera compris par tout le monde, plutôt que d'essayer de le traduire. Par contre, je rencontre plus souvent "faire un checkout" que "checkouter"

Comment: Ce n'est pas pour traduire un texte, simple curiosité.

Comment: Ça aurait peut-être été mieux de choisir des exemples d'un gestionnaire de versions moderne. Par exemple, quelqu'un oserait-il traduire *pull* et *push* (terminologie commune pour à peu près tous les gestionnaires de version distribués) de façon littérale?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Ça n'invalide pas cette question-ci, mais c'en est une excellente en soit. Je n'ai malheureusement aucune expérience personnelle avec ces gestionnaires de version distribués.

Comment: J'ai déjà eu du mal à comprendre les nuances du _checkout_ selon SVN comparé à Clearcase, alors si en plus on m'embrouille avec _extraction_ ou _récupération_...

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez *push* peut se traduire par *pousser*. Il m'est déjà arrivé de lire des phrases comme "*j'ai poussé 3 commits*". Par contre, "*décentralisé*" conviendrait mieux que "*moderne*" dans ta phrase "*un gestionnaire de versions moderne*". SVN n'est pas plus dépassé que `git` d'un point de vue gestionnaire de versions. Après ce n'est pas non plus le lieu pour déclencher des "guerres de clocher" geek...

Comment: Je dirais plutôt Verrou pour Lock puisqu'il est utilisé comme un nom et non comme un verbe, ex : Get lock, Release lock

Comment: @hoang Bonne remarque, mais "Obtenir le verrou/Relâcher le verrou" serait plus clair que "Verrouiller/Déverrouiller"?

Comment: @MPelletier quid de "steal lock" ? Avons nous un verbe pour ça ?

Comment: @hoang Je ne suis pas familier avec cette expression.

Comment: En France, les développeurs que je connais ne traduisent pas et utilisent les mots anglais directement :-(

Comment: @Frank Au Québec, le gouvernement recommande des expressions (voir ma réponse mentionnant l'OQLF), mais les développeurs n'utilisent que les mots anglais, sauf pour "Pull", on peut parfois entendre "pousser".

Comment: Oui - dans certains communautés bilingues aux US, on mélange allègrement le français et l'anglais, ou on traduit mot à mot pour un effet comique ("je vais suer tes fesses", "j'attends pour toi", "je sweate", "on se fait un drive le weekend prochain"...). Je ne dis pas que c'est bien, je dis juste que ça existe, et les communautés françaises aux US ne sont pas petites (>70,000 rien que dans la Bay), les gens retournent en France, donc les ingés software qui reviennent de la Silicon Valley (par exemple) vont forcément revenir avec du vocabulaire anglais...

Comment: Vu dans un forum juste à l'instant: "Je suis seulement intéressé appliquées en France sur les capital gains." - c'est hors-sujet pour git/svn... mais c'est un autre exemple vivant de mélange français/anglais.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

J'utilise pour ma part **téléchargement initial** ou **récupération** pour le *checkout* et **publication**, **validation** ou **enregistrement** pour le *commit*.

SVN utilise le vocabulaire *extraction* et *propagation* sur la ligne de commande. *Extraction* est un mauvais mot, car la fonction d'extraction existe déjà et sert un tout autre but. Archiver n'est pas sémantiquement correct, puisque l'archivage n'est qu'un effet secondaire de la gestion de version. *Propagation* n'est pas trop mal, mais je préfère tout de même publier, qui est plus dans l'esprit (rien ne se propage au final, c'est une opération unique).

Comment: Quitte à devoir traduire, +1. Mais je plussoie surtout [le commentaire de BatchyX](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3089/comment-traduire-les-termes-relies-aux-gestionnaires-de-version#comment5203_3089)

Answer (score 3):

Dans le cadre de l'utilisation du gestionnaire de code SVN, leur vocabulaire donne exactement le *point de vue du client* de la base de référence :

> **Checkout --> Extraction** : je n'ai rien sur mon poste (ou ma version est obsolète), *j'extrais* (avec suppression des références
>   existantes) tout le code nécessaire de la base de référence.
>
> *C'est une sélection de données nécessairement cohérentes dans leur globalité.*
>
> **Commit --> Propagation** : je contribue à l'évolution des programmes, non seulement je valide et sauvegarde mon travail, mais *je le propage*, pour que les collègues puissent l'utiliser.

C'est un vocabulaire qui l'on peut appliquer pour tout échange de même type avec une base de donnée, *lorsque l'on se situe en tant que client et lorsque la validation de la saisie dépasse le simple enregistrement de données*.

Comment: "Commit -> Propagation" ne marche pas vraiment pour les DVCS (Git, Mercurial, ...): on fait des "commits" locaux. Même pour SVN, c'est pas terrible. Propager donne une idée qu'un "commit" va plus loin que le serveur SVN, ce qui n'est pas vraiment le cas, en tous cas pas par cette seule action.

Comment: @Bruno C'est  la notion de mise à jour complémentaire des fichiers cachés, la réorganisation des données d'une base individuelle dans une base partagée qui me fait opter pour cette traduction, en restant bien entendu du point de vue de l'utilisateur. Alors que du point de vue du DBA, vous avez tout à fait raison, commit<->sauvegarde sur disque (sur le poste client aussi), la notion de propagation sous entend alors la seconde sauvegarde dans la base partagée. Pour un manuel utilisateur : propager, pour un manuel responsable serveur : sauvegarder me semblent convenir.

Comment: Je ne pensais pas au DBA. C'est plutôt la notion de propagation qui ne va pas. Pour moi, on propage une information en la donnant à plusieurs personnes ou en comptant sur elles pour la propager à d'autres. Quand on fait un "commit" en utilisant SVN, on n'envoie le commit qu'à un serveur, qui peut (ou pas) être utilisé par d'autres. Le fait qu'il y ait éventuellement propagation fait partie d'un autre processus (le fait que d'autres fassent des "checkouts"). Quant au DVCS, fait un "commit" via Git/Mercurial n'a vraiment rien à voir avec propager, puisque c'est principalement local (sans "push")

Answer (score 2):

Complément d'information: l'OQLF recommende [extraction](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8356424) pour "checkout".

Answer (score 1):

L'OQLF [recommande](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870443) *archiver*, et mentionne aussi *valider* et *soumettre*. Personnellement je n'ai malheureusement du tout l'expérience nécessaire avec ce genre de systèmes pour évaluer s'il s'agit de la bonne "opération".

Comment: Merci. Pas surprenant que l'OQLF opte pour un verbe qui ne signifie pas tout à fait la bonne chose...

Comment: Dans un cadre *open source* "soumettre" semble parfait car il renvoit à la notion d'évaluation par ses pairs.